# Как вызвать функцию из main()?

Tags: c++

Я только начал изучать указатели (*1 день*) и не могу понять как передать указатель из функции **create_matrix()** в **main()**, *а в ней уже вызвать другую функцию (print_matrix) с параметром в качестве указателя (массива) из* **create_matrix()**.

Если не трудно, то пожалуйста, сделайте замечания по коду.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void print_matrix(int** matrix, int size_l, int size_s)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < size_l; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < size_s; y++)
        {
            cout << matrix[x][y] << setw(3);
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}


int create_matrix(int size_m, int size_l, int size_s)
{
    int** matrix = new int* [size_m];
    for (int i = 0; i < size_m; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = new int[size_m];
    }

    cout << "Enter elements of matrix : " << endl;
    for (int x = 0; x < size_l; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < size_s; y++)
        {
            cout << "[" 
                 << x 
                 << "," 
                 << y 
                 << "]" 
                 << " << ";
            cin >> matrix[x][y];
        }
    }

    return **matrix;
}


int main()
{
    unsigned int array_size;
    unsigned int number_of_lines;
    unsigned int number_of_strings;

    cout << "Enter number of lines : ";
    cin >> number_of_lines;
    cout << "Enter number of strings : ";
    cin >> number_of_strings;


    array_size = number_of_lines * number_of_strings;

    create_matrix(array_size, number_of_lines, number_of_strings);
    //print_matrix(matrix, number_of_lines, number_of_strings);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если вы возвращаете `int**`, то так и пишите - `int** create_matrix(...`, а не `int create_matrix(...`. Ну, а в `main` выполните соответствующее присваивание переменной того же типа. Которую потом передайте в `print...`.

Comment: @Harry, спасибо вам, у меня все получилось !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Спасибо пользователю @Harry за ответ !**

Рабочий вариант выглядит вот так

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void print_matrix(int** matrix, int size_l, int size_s)
{
    cout << "Matrix :" << endl;

    for (int x = 0; x < size_l; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < size_s; y++)
        {
            cout << matrix[x][y] << setw(3);
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

int** create_matrix(int size_m, int size_l, int size_s)
{
    int** matrix = new int* [size_m];
    for (int i = 0; i < size_m; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = new int[size_m];
    }

    cout << "Enter elements of matrix : " << endl;
    for (int x = 0; x < size_l; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < size_s; y++)
        {
            cout << "[" 
                 << x 
                 << "," 
                 << y 
                 << "]" 
                 << " << ";
            cin >> matrix[x][y];
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}


int main()
{
    unsigned int array_size;
    unsigned int number_of_lines;
    unsigned int number_of_strings;

    cout << "Enter number of lines : ";
    cin >> number_of_lines;
    cout << "Enter number of strings : ";
    cin >> number_of_strings;


    array_size = number_of_lines * number_of_strings;

    int** matrix = create_matrix(array_size, number_of_lines, number_of_strings);
    print_matrix(matrix, number_of_lines, number_of_strings);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что за белиберда с `size_m`, `size_l` и `size_s`? В `create_matrix` создается матрица размера `[size_m][size_m]` , а работа с ней затем ведется как с `[size_l][size_s]`. В чем тут глубинная идея? Когда вам нужна матрица `[5][8]`, вы зачем-то создаете матрицу `[40][40]`. Когда вам нужна матрица `[7][12]`, вы зачем-то создаете матрицу `[84][84]`. Зачем???